# Sqlite TimeStamp convert integer to time

Tags: java, android, datetime, unix-timestamp

How this turned `1439930897000 = 1:18` is time now hours? That format was how! I've used this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm) but did not receive results.

Comment: Can you post your code? What is the SQL query you used and how are you accessing the time in Java?

Comment: I do not have access to application code. But I can read the database. The number of hours had been stored in the database.

Comment: @Negar It is the number of seconds, not hours. You can calculate the time it represents and add it to "Jan 01 1970". This way you can point to a specific timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this number is an hour but do not know how! Perhaps in its date

Comment: Thanks to friends, I found the answer. Using System.currentTimeMillis (); You can take time to become number.
This is a help site.
http://www.epochconverter.com

Answer (score 0):

That is the Unix Time. That number is the number of seconds since "Jan 01 1970". The function you have used calculates the appropriate date and time by using the provided number of seconds.

You can read more about the Unix Time [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Thanks to friends, I found the answer. Using System.currentTimeMillis (); You can take time to become number.
This is a help site.
http://www.epochconverter.com